# ios label.text null

Tags: iphone, ios, label, uilabel

I'm setting a UILabel but is returning null.

.h file:

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) UILabel *label;
```

.m file :

```
@synthesize label;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.label.text=@"some text";
 [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I check the value of label and is null. Can any body tell me why is null?
Can anybody tellme what I'm doing wrong?

How can I set the label from a different viewcontroller?

Comment: Your not allocating or initializing the UILabel. Nor is it an IBOutlet to an interface builder file. You should follow more starting tutorials and guides before posting a question like this.

Comment: if you have got your solution then please accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vimal's answer does not completely answer your question. You indeed need to add this in:

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

But you still need to set the frame of the label and actually add the label to the view:

```
self.label.frame = CGRectMake(30.0f, 30.0f, 60.0f, 30.0f);
[self.view addSubview: self.label];
```

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko - Thanks. Forgot about that part too.

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad

add below code as the first line

```
self.label = [[UILabel alloc]init]; // allocate and initialize the label object
```

Answer (score 0):

it would be amazing if you try to reach your outlets in the `-viewWillAppear:` method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.label.text = @"some text";
}
```